How to improve the performance using Parallel.ForEachAsync
I have below code which will call couple of services and finally add the items to collection. I am using Parallel.ForEachAsync for fast performance for processing each id in request. But it's taking 10+secs for returning response.
public async Task<ModifiedCollection> GetUpdates(Request request)
{
    ModifiedCollection modifiedCollection = new ModifiedCollection();
    List<string> Ids = request.Ids.Distinct().ToList();
    var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 };

    if (Ids.Any())
    {
       await Parallel.ForEachAsync(Ids, options, async (id,token) =>
        {
            var globalId = "";
            var result = await _provider.GetList(id, request.IsActive);

            var baseValue = result.FirstOrDefault();

                if (baseValue?.CustId.FirstOrDefault() == Constants.ABC)
                {
                    var predicate = _provider.GetPredicate(
                                 type: baseValue.type,
                                 id: null);

                    var matter = await _provider.GetItem(request.IsActive, predicate);

                   
                    if (matter != null && matter.CustId.Contains(request.ToRequest.CustId.FirstOrDefault()))
                    {
                        result = await _provider.GetList(matter.MapId, request.IsActive);
                        globalId = id;
                    }
                }

                result = BackDraw(result, request.FromRequest.CustId.FirstOrDefault());

                await Parallel.ForEachAsync(result, options, async (item,token) =>
                {
                    var IsValid = true;
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.ToRequest.EligDate))
                        IsValid = CheckEligibility(item, Convert.ToDateTime(request.ToRequest.EligDate));

                    if (IsValid)
                    {
                        var resultMatter = await _provider.GetStructure(item);
                        var uItem = await GetUItem(resultMatter);

                        if (uItem != null)
                        {
                            if (!uItem.rNotes.IsNullOrEmpty() && !uItem.property.IsNullOrEmpty())
                            {
                                modifiedCollection.ModifiedItem.Add(new ModifiedItem
                                {
                                    Id = item.ObjectId,
                                    Version = int.Parse(item.Version),
                                                                       
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        });
    }
    return modifiedCollection;
}

Class defination is as below
public class ModifiedCollection
{
     public ConcurrentBag<ModifiedItem> ModifiedItemBag { get; set; }
     public Updates()
     {
         UpdatesCollectionBag = new ConcurrentBag<ModifiedItem>();            
     }
}

If I replace the Parallel.ForEachAsync with just foreach , it's taking is 8+ secs. How can I make this fast? I need to make improvements in performance of this code. Any help would be appreciated. TIA

Before you start improving performance, you should first measure which part of your code is the bottleneck. Often, it is just a handfull of lines of code which are slow. If you don't know, which lines these are, it will be very hard.

@SomeBody DB calls are working fine with expected fast response, but the problem is if I passed, 10-20 ids in request then there is a performance issue.

As @SomeBody said, do you integrate your service with any other external api? Did you check the avarage response time?

@ViniciusAndrade average response time is currently 8+ secs. I need to take it down to 3-4 secs at least

10-20 shouldn't bother the DB too much. And you only do 5 in parallel. I agree, you should first return to sequential processing and then take measurements and go from there. My assumption would be that you can get better performance increase by batching DB requests. (Querying for a range if ids in one query, rather each individually, for example). Then maybe analyze if you can shift some intermediate steps completely to the db by using joins and projections, in order to minimize data transfer roundtrips...

No, what I meant was: did you isolate your problem? did you check how long it takes to perform a single request?

Also, there is a ForEachAsync inside the ForEachAsync. If you cannot avoid that 1:n explosion, I'd have the outer ForEachAsync act as a producer and have a different consumer that does the inner step, so those work like a pipeline. (If it cannot be avoided otherwise in the first place).

Nesting Parallel operations the one inside the other is not a good idea. You could take a look at this question, or this Microsoft article.

@Fildor I am using cosmos db and it has partition already.

@TheodorZoulias I have removed the inner Parallel loop and response time is still the same.

Sure, I was not expecting to make much of a difference. I mentioned it because when people are nesting Parallel loops, it's usually an act of desperation. Most likely your bottleneck is the database, and parallelism rarely helps when the queries are slow. Your database is struggling, because (I assume) the queries are not optimized, and bombarding it with multiple queries won't make it respond faster.

@TheodorZoulias how I can debug  query on cosmos?

I have no idea!
